# How to set "viaIR: true" for solidity compiling?

Tags: solidity, remix

When I compile solidity script and I get advice to get "viaIR: true", but I don't know how to do it. Shall I get more details?

Comment: What development framework are you using? Foundry, Hardhat, etc.

Comment: I use Hardhat and Remix, and both of them raise the same error.

Comment: If you want to enable IR in Remix, you have to use [standard json](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/using-the-compiler.html#compiler-api).

Comment: Consider using [Foundry](https://getfoundry.sh), in which you can enable IR via a simple setting in the Foundry config file.

Comment: it seems a little complicated.

Comment: Foundry is much less complicated than Hardhat, since you're writing your tests in Solidity, the same language that you're writing your contracts in.

Answer (score 4):

Inside your hardhat.config file, add "viaIR: true" as a property under "solidity":

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.9",
    settings: {
      viaIR: true,
    },
  },
};
```